# Move Windows boot manager?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I'm being booted straight into BIOS.

It happened after I removed an m.2 SSD so that I could return it since its basically broken.  (It shows up ok as raw but I'm unable to format. I had it for perhaps a year, but it started having problems reading)

When I put it back in I can boot into Windows normally.

I've tried to (with very limited knowledge) to fix boot by using a USB stick with Windows on it to reinstall boot. The automatic troubleshooter returned that it could not fix it.

I tried to fix it in CMD in the recovery (with the m2 out). I did the `diskpart` and list volume command and C: show up as raw even if it's not.

Now I'm guessing that the boot stuff I need to load Windows and see C: as not raw is on the m.2 SSD.

Am I wrong? If so any suggestion?

And if I am right, how to fix it?

For clarification: i have two ssds. One kingston and one m2ssd. The kingston is C: with windows on and the m2ssd is D:. Without the m2ssd   windows bootable usb stick dont recognize C: as ntfs, but just as raw so i cant use bcdboot it seems

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bcdboot` to install the Windows bootloader. Note that on nearly all post-XP systems it is installed on a *separate* partition – the "EFI System Partition" on disks prepared for UEFI boot, "Microsoft System Reserved Partition" on disks set up for BIOS/CSM/legacy boot.

(That's probably why your SSD is still capable of booting an OS despite having a corrupted C:\ filesystem – the bootloader wasn't on C:\ to begin with, but on a partition *next to* the one you call C:, and the OS installation that it's set up to boot isn't actually stored on that disk either.)

You need to make sure your main OS disk contains such a partition before trying to install a bootloader there; there are already quite few posts here on this site about creating it via diskpart, as well as about using bcdboot.

> show up as raw even if it's not.

That's not "boot stuff". That's just NTFS filesystem support – any Windows system can recognize any NTFS filesystem on any disk, as long as the basic file structures are still there.

If the recovery Windows system doesn't recognize a partition as NTFS, then it really just means that partition no longer contains a valid NTFS system, regardless of any bootloader.

Comment: For clarification: i have two ssds. One kingston and one m2ssd. The kingston is C: with windows on and the m2ssd is D:. Without the m2ssd   windows bootable usb stick dont recognize C: as ntfs, but just as raw so i cant use bcdboot it seems